# ASP NET CORE MVC Получение данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть сущность Post, при создании которой необходимо подгрузить список Tag и записать их в месте в базу.

```
    public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли передать данные из базы List в View до обращения к контроллеру? Если да, то как это можно реализвать?

Comment: 1) Зачем? Опишите вашу проблему 2) Если вы не хотите использовать контроллер, может вы зря начали писать на MV*C*?

Comment: @tym3267 Контроллеры есть, нужно чтобы при создании поста подгружались все теги, и можно было выбрать некоторые из них и сохранить вместе с постом

Comment: А View  тут причем?

Comment: Как правило, для подгрузки тегов используется сервис, который при наборе тегов подгружает их, к примеру по AJAX (а-ля WordPress).